# Restar días a fecha datetime (SQL y PHP)

Tags: php, sql, datetime

Quiero que me muestre una serie de solicitudes de la base de datos y el usuario tiene que introducir de hace cuántos días quiere el informe (X días).

El problema que tengo es que me **resta bien las fechas, pero si no coinciden las horas no saca resultados**. Me gustaría que descarte las horas y solo se quede con la fecha, pero no sé cómo modificar lo que ya tengo...

```
private static function exportaInforme($numDias = null)
{
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select(array('s.*'));
    $query->from('solicitudes AS s');
    $query->where("(s.estado='6' AND s.fecha = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL '".$numDias."' DAY))"); 
    $db->setQuery((string) $query);
    $result = $db->loadObjectList();

    return $result;
}
```

**¿Cómo resto X días a una fecha de la base de datos y que solo tenga en cuenta la fecha pero no las horas?**

Comment: puedes pespecificar tu motor de base de datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El Problema es que estas comparando una fecha con marca de tiempo y otra sin marca de tiempo para poder realizar tu cunsulta correctamente debes eliminar la marca de tiempo de ambas fechas, ya que DATE_SUB(CURDATE() es `'2017-10-19'` `s.fecha` debe tener el mismo formato.

```
private static function exportaInforme($numDias = null)
{
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select(array('s.*'));
    $query->from('solicitudes AS s');
    $query->where("(s.estado='6' AND DATE(s.fecha) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL '".$numDias."' DAY))"); 
    $db->setQuery((string) $query);
    $result = $db->loadObjectList();

    return $result;
}
```

También puedes usar la funcion `DATEDIFF()` que solo compara las dos fecha y devuelve el resultado en días.

```
private static function exportaInforme($numDias = null)
{
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select(array('s.*'));
    $query->from('solicitudes AS s');
    $query->where("(s.estado='6' AND DATEDIFF(s.fecha ,CURDATE()) = 1)"); 
    $db->setQuery((string) $query);
    $result = $db->loadObjectList();

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Perfecto! Justo ese era mi problema y me había bloqueado en cómo solucionarlo, muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

El problema no es la resta de día, el problema es la comparación entre fechas, una tiene su parte horaria y la otra no, es claro que no van a coincidir. Lo que puedes hacer es usar [`DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) (o si fuera oracle [`DATE()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.0-en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)) para quitar la parte horaria de la fecha. Podemos descartar que el `DATE_SUB` devuelva la fecha con hora por que `CURDATE()` no incluye la hora, así que imagino que el problema está en el dato de la tabla: `s.fecha`, prueba modificar la comparación de esta forma:

```
AND DATE(s.fecha) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL '".$numDias."' DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes comparar las fechas sin la hora mediante:

```
Convert(date, getdate())
```

Te dejo la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql).

Answer (score 0):

Si tu campo es Datetime, entonces debes utilizar rangos:

```
SELECT 
    t.fecha_datetime
     DATE_SUB(Curdate(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) as fecha_desde,
     DATE_SUB(Curdate(), INTERVAL 9 DAY) as fecha_hasta
FROM tabla as t
WHERE t.fecha_Datetime >= DATE_SUB(Curdate(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
      AND t.fecha_Datetime < DATE_SUB(Curdate(), INTERVAL 9 DAY);
```

Presta atención a la segunda comparación es estrictamente menor al día siguiente (fecha_hasta). De esta forma la consulta por el campo fecha_Datetime es **sargable**, es decir, puede utilizar índices que estén disponibles.